# Google Maps and Jquery tabs: Maps loads black rectangle over all content - Only in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, tabs, maps

Ok, I'm sure everyone here is sick of hearing about Gmaps and Jquery tabs given the amount of questions about it on here, but this is an odd one.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
http://scotbrut.co.uk/screenshot-chrome-maps-tabs-issue.png

And you can see it for yourself, live, on the website here (make sure to view it in Chrome):
http://scotbrut.co.uk/archive/hunterian-art-gallery/
...or on any of the archive entries on the site.

Basically, the Google Map window, displayed in the last tab of each archive entry, appears to load a black rectangle over the top of all the other tabs and content (though you can click through it to select text/click links etc.) You can make it disappear by clicking on the Gallery or Map tab.

The issue appears to be limited to Google Chrome (win & mac) so far as I can tell; I have tested the site in Firefox and Safari on my mac and Firefox, Chrome and IE7 through 10 on windows with no issue.

Even more bizarre is that the site was working perfectly fine until yesterday when this problem reared its ugly head. There have been *no* changes made to the code or even the content over the past week, and no plugin or Wordpress updates applied, so I cannot fathom for the life of me why this has suddenly happened?

*Any* input whatsoever would be greatly appreciated — all I have managed to diagnose so far is that it is an issue with a combination of Google Maps, Chrome and jquery tabs...but it was working perfectly for nearly 3 months before! Normally I would just put it down to my shoddy coding and google around until I found a solution (usually on here) but this has really stumped me.

---

Basic site info:

The site is built on Wordpress 3.5, the google maps are displayed using the WP Google Maps plugin (so they are called with a shortcode), and the tabs are just a basic jquery tab set up. I can't remember which one specifically but they all seem to be basically the same.

*If there is any code or whatever needed to help diagnose the issue please tell me and I will happily oblige.*

Also — this is my first post on here so go easy :) haha.

Comment: works fine for me under chrome win7

Comment: Thanks roasted - that's interesting. I can reproduce the issue in Chrome on win7 as can the client on his PC. Perhaps it is a simple cookie/cache issue? That said I tested it on a clean/vanilla install of Chrome on my win7 VM. I will try clearing my mac's cache and see if it makes any difference. Cheers :)

Comment: Update: cleared cache, cookies, etc., and problem persists for me.

Comment: To test it, i click on 'Map' tab then on 'Planning & Design' but no black rectangle appear.  What do you have if you inspect this black rectangle (right click -> inspect element) ?

Comment: "Even more bizarre is that the site was working perfectly fine until yesterday" Could you check your chrome version and post it here to compare to mine (Chrome use auto-update) ?

Comment: For me (and the client) the rectangle only appears on the initial page load. It will disappear if you go to the Gallery or Map tab. I have tried inspecting the element and it doesn't really tell me much other than it is the google maps window (also because the rectangle is click-through-able it tries to inspect the content of whatever is under it so you have to wade through the code to the map tab section anyway). I'm wondering if it could be a Chrome update? What version are you on? I am on the latest build.

Comment: Aha you beat me to it - yes I am on auto update and the latest build of 27.0.1453.93

Comment: Im on 26.0.1410.64 m with an error log for last update. I'll try in less than 30 minutes (i have to move now) on an other computer which should be on 27.x.x.x (lastest) to test it. I'll let you know

Comment: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/stable-channel-release.html it would appear the version the client and I are running was only released on the 21st of May. I think we have our culprit, but I will await your results roasted. :)

Comment: Ok, tested on 27.x build and yes i have same bug as you. So, it's related to chrome last update. To fix this? Well, maybe try to append the google map only when map tab is clicked the first time. But yes, for sure it's a weird bug.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot roasted. Very annoying bug! I'll have a fiddle around and see what I can do. I hope they fix it in the next update :/

Comment: Filed a bug report with google: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244070&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

Right so I'm rather impatient when it comes to these things and am not willing to wait for Google to fix the bug (if indeed it is a bug...personally I think it is, even Safari, another webkit browser, had no issue with the code), so I found a workaround similar to what Roasted suggested.

The problem seemed to stem from `{visibility: hidden;}` being applied to the map. For some reason chrome was rendering this as the black box you can see in the above screen shot. When it was set to visible, the map would show but over all the other tabs/content. It seemed as though the visibility rule was being interpreted by chrome as meaning hide the map content (so the image tiles etc) but now the rest of the container.

The workaround I found was part of the jquery tabs code that hides/shows each tab as you click on the links by adding or removing a class with `{visibility: hidden;}` or `{visibility: visible;}`.

All I did was to add a class with `{visibility: hidden;}` (in this case `.novis`) to the overall map tab container div so that the entire map tab was hidden on load, rather than just the map itself. Then I simply gave the map tab link a unique ID (in this case `#mappage`) for the Javascript to hook onto and wrote a bit of script to say that clicking on the map tab link removes the no visibility `.novis` class. Seems to work fine in all browsers now.

Here's the code I added:

```
$("ul.tabs li#mappage").click(function() {
            $("div#mapcontainer").removeClass("novis");
            //$(this).addClass("active"); 
            });
```

And this is the overall jquery tab code (with my snippet at the end):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Default Action
        $(".tab_content").css({'visibility':'hidden'  , 'position':'absolute'});
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
        $(".tab_content:first").css({'visibility':'visible' , 'position':'static'}); 

        //On Click Event
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
        $(".tab_content").css({'visibility':'hidden' , 'position':'absolute'}); 
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        $(activeTab).css({'visibility':'visible'  , 'position':'static'});
        return false;
        });
        $("ul.tabs li#mappage").click(function() {
        $("div#mapcontainer").removeClass("novis");
        //$(this).addClass("active"); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this makes sense. I doubt this will be much use for anyone else but I though I may as well post what I discovered. And thanks again to Roasted for pointing me int he right direction :)